# Compute the matrix of T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear map given by 
$$
T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3, x_1 - x_3)
$$

Compute the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $(1,1,1), (1,-1,1), (1,2,2)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the basis $(1,1), (1,-1)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

I input the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $T$ and got the following:

$$\begin{align*}
T(1,1,1) &= (6,0) \\
T(1,-1,1) &= (2,0) \\
T(1,2,2) &= (11,-1)
\end{align*}$$

Then I multiplied the above transformation in a matrix with the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 6&0 \\ 2&0 \\ 11 & -1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&-1 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 6&6 \\ 2&2 \\ 10&12 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

Thus I think my answer is the result of the matrix multiplication. I am not sure if I am understanding all the steps correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you think that you must compute $T(1,1,1)$, $T(1,-1,1)$, and $T(1,2,2)$. But, after that, you must express those vectors as linear combinations of $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. And you have:

- $T(1,1,1)=(6,0)=3\times(1,1)+3\times(1,-1)$;
- $T(1,-1,1)=(2,0)=1\times(1,1)+1\times(1,-1)$;
- $T(1,2,2)=(11,-1)=5\times(1,1)+6\times(1,-1)$.

So, the answer is$$\begin{bmatrix}3&1&5\\3&1&6\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Is there a more mathematical method for finding the linear combinations (in this case, it was easy to see which scalar values would be valid, but maybe that isn't always going to be the case)?

Comment: @Have you learned about change-of-basis matrices yet? If not, then a systematic way is to set up systems of linear equations for the coefficients relative to the new basis.